# Completely center an image?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a div and an image within the div. The image size will vary.

I want it to be centered horizontally and vertically. Css verticle align does't seem to work.

Any tricks? I can use php, css or Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't know how you use it, so probably my solution won't fit.*

When you implement the image as a 'background-image' within the div you can easily center it with 'background-position':

```
#div {
background-image: url(./image.png);
background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Thats a great idea. I need the image to link to something but I may be able to get away with a transparent span and use this suggestion. Will report back :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to align horizontally by using

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Centring vertically isn't easy with [CSS](http://www.tomwalsham.com/post.php?id=70) (at least not in IE6/7). It's relatively easy to do it with tables.

You say you have jQuery available. You can kick any browser into gear by applying JavaScript. But of course without JS enabled/supported, your page will not appear correctly.

CSS's vertical-align property is only meant to be used within something with `display: table-cell` (which itself *should* be in something with `display: table`).

If you had

```
<div id="container"><img src="my-image.png" alt="" /></div>
```

You could use jQuery to center it like this (as in the suggestion by [plexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592528/completely-center-an-image/1597757#1597757))

```
var imageSrc = $('#container img').attr('src');

$('#container').css({ backgroundImage: 'url(' + imageSrc + ')', backgroundPosition: 'center enter' });
```

Comment: Well its a Jquery intensive site, so I dont mind it looking a little off when javascript is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .image-container {
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background:#ccc;
    }
    .image-container .image {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
        background:red;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
    }
</style>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src="****.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.